# PHP add int values to another int, but limit the result

Tags: php

I have got the following unknown int value:

```
$unknown=5; // could be 875 or any other int number
```

I need to add 255 to $unknown:

```
$needle=255+$unknown;
```

But I don't want the $needle to be bigger than 512. Is there any function to do this in the same line that calculates the $needle?

For instance, I known I can do it with an if ($needle > 512) $needle=512; but I was wondering whether there is a clever way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$needle = min($unknown+255, 512);
```

[PHP `min()` manual page](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.min.php)

Comment: @JakeGould thanks. Though, I've seen this trick being used in various languages and places, so I can't really claim originality. `;)`